# how to convert raw br in gsp to break row?

Tags: grails, gsp

In my gsp page is the following code

```
<p>

        ${ confirmationTemplate?.body?.replace('\n', '<br/>') }


    </p>
```

The page renders as follows

```
> Dear Participant, <br/> <br/>Thanks for registering to our event. The
> event will start shortly. <br/> <br/>Please collect your bibs before
> the race. <br/> <br/>Cheers, <br/>Swat Kats
```

The < br/> should not be printed but that should cause new line. How can i solve this problem? I appreciate any help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Look at this article http://mrhaki.blogspot.ru/2013/11/grails-goodness-generating-raw-output.html

```
 ${raw(confirmationTemplate?.body?.replace('\n', '<br/>'))}
```

The example above will work with grails version > 2.3

Comment: it gives an error raw() is not applicable for String

Comment: What grails version do you use?

Comment: i am using old version. 2.2

Comment: try this one ${ confirmationTemplate?.body?.replace('\n', '<br/>')?.encodeAsHTML() }

Comment: i think i tried that one as well and didn't help. i think the problem is that ${} will encode the string rather than just use raw string outputted. is there a way in 2.2 to prevent this encoding for this specific part

Comment: encodeAsHTML() gives the output: Dear Participant, &lt;br/&gt; &lt;br/&gt;Thanks for registering to our event. The event will start shortly. &lt;br/&gt; &lt;br/&gt;Please collect your bibs before the race. &lt;br/&gt; &lt;br/&gt;Cheers, &lt;br/&gt;Swat Kats

Comment: Very strange. JUst tested the following code in 2.2.4 def html = """Dear Participant,

Thanks for registering to our event. The
 event will start shortly.

 Please collect your bibs before
 the race.

 Cheers,
 Swat Kats"""
 %>
 
 ${html.replace('\n', '</br>')}

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43317602/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions that apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: @MaximTulupov my version is 2.2.0 so i guess that is the reason it is not working. i solved the problem by splitting the string at \n delim and then using each to iterate and place the parts within p.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%request.setAttribute("vEnter", "\n");%>
    ${fn:replace(blindItem.blindShowModeStr,vEnter,"<BR />") }
```

Comment: is there a cleaner way to achieve this goal?