# How to use replaceAll in gsp?

Tags: groovy, gsp

I have this code in my [gsp](/questions/tagged/gsp) file:

```
<span class="highlighted-data-value">${address}</span>
```

`address` variable holds a value similar to:

> Address line 1, City, Country

I want to line break on comas, but it looks like I am not able to do so.

Is there a way to do `replaceAll` inside that gsp file? Something like `${address.replaceAll(",","\\n")}`

Ideally I would not want to use the controller, but to do it directly in gsp file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`${address.replaceAll(",","\\n")}` didn't produce expected result, because it broke String into 3 lines, but HTML renders it as a single line when there is no `<br />` tag. Instead you can try breaking your String as:

```
${raw(address.replaceAll(',', '<br />'))}
```

This will produce a result that should render an address broken to 3 lines:

```
<span class="highlighted-data-value">Address line 1<br /> City<br /> Country</span>
```

Alternatively you can split this String in controller, pass a list to a view and then use [`<g:each in=""></g:each>`](http://docs.grails.org/3.1.1/ref/Tags/each.html) loop.

Comment: tried the .replaceAll inside the ${}, getting this error in the console.
No signature of method: xxxxx.Address.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [,, \n]. Stacktrace follows: [GrailsExceptionResolver]..

Personally lost with this error message, maybe you have a clue?

I will try to see if I can split it in the controller then

Comment: AH, I got it.... I had to do `toString()` on that address. Don't know why I did not try to understand of the error completely :D Thanks tho!

Comment: with replacing with <br /> it just added that as a string into the span. I will see if I find a way to line break it

Comment: @OFFLlNE Yeah, my assumption was that `${address}` is a `String` type basing on the input you pasted in the question.

Comment: it is weird tho that it displays it as Adress line 1<br /> City <br /> Country in the gsp (my PDF) right now, I am trying to figure out, but if any1 might have ideas why, I am happy to hear some suggestions

Comment: GOT IT. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43317231/how-to-convert-raw-br-in-gsp-to-break-row/43317630
`raw()` did the job.
Thank you all

Comment: Perfect! :) Updated the answer as well